# django-websocker error: ValueError: message object is not of type RedisMessage

Tags: django

I'm learning how to setup django-websocket with redis https://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#use-redispublisher-from-inside-django-views and I'm calling it like this

```
message =  "Percentage {0}% \t {1}/{2} \t {3}".format(percentage, counter, (width * height), delta)
print message
socket = RenderView()
socket.get(request, message)
```

in the view

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
from ws4redis.publisher import RedisPublisher

class RenderView(View):
    facility = 'render-view'
    audience = {'broadcast': True}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RenderView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.redis_publisher = RedisPublisher(facility=self.facility, **self.audience)

    def get(self, request, message):
        self.redis_publisher.publish_message(message)
```

I'm getting this error

```
    socket.get(request, message)
  File "/home/samuel/Documents/code/revamp/gallery/socket.py", line 13, in get
    self.redis_publisher.publish_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ws4redis/redis_store.py", line 110, in publish_message
    raise ValueError('message object is not of type RedisMessage')
ValueError: message object is not of type RedisMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same thing just now and resolved it by doing the following

```
from ws4redis.redis_store import RedisMessage

message = RedisMessage('Your message in here')
publisher.publish_message(message)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `message` into `RedisMessage` class.